# Грамотное построение предложения

Tags: стилистика

Как грамотно сказать: "спросить пару вопросов" или "задать пару вопросов"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

В выражении ***спросить пару вопросов*** есть тавтология, поэтому грамотным является выражение ***задать пару вопросов***.

Answer (score 1):

Даже один вопрос нельзя спросить.